# Combining keyframes animations into one

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I have an image that I want to "walk across" a div then at the end flip around horizontally and head back the other way. I have created a codepen here: https://codepen.io/jessiemele/pen/rGQWWE. The tinyWalk animation gets very bouncy towards the end, right before it turns and heads back to the start, I'm assuming it is form the image hitting the top of the div. I'm wondering if there is a way to combine these 2 animations to just run them on the image so I don't have to run tinyWalk on the div. My code is here:

```
<div class="catapillarBox">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/0XPhWfE.jpg" class="caterpillar" 
alt="caterpillar drawing" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="blueBox">
<h5>I'm your box</h5>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blueBox {
  background-color: #1d88eb;
  width: 875px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 125px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
}
img.caterpillar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 125px;
  left:0;
  -webkit-animation: walk 20s forwards infinite linear;
  animation: walk 20s forwards infinite linear;
  z-index: 3;
}
@keyframes walk{
  0% { left: 0; transform: rotateY(0deg);}
  49% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
  50% {left: 700px; transform: rotateY(180deg);}
  99% {transform: rotateY(180deg);}
  100% {left: 0; transform: rotateY(0deg);
}    
.catapillarBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: tinywalk 500ms linear alternate infinite;
  animation: tinywalk 500ms linear alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes tinywalk {
  0%{ transform: rotate(0);}
  25%{ transform: rotate(-1deg);}
  50%{ transform: rotate(1deg);}
  75%{ transform: rotate(-1deg);}
  100%{ transform: rotate(0);}
}
```

Comment: It looks like it is working to me (your codepen does what you are describing). Did you solve this?

Comment: Hi Jack, I just updated my question. I got the back and forth and flip to work but I'm seeing a lot of bouncing with having the tinyWalk on the div instead of the image, it's very noticeable towards the end before it flips and walks back to the start. I'm wondering is there is a way I can combine them and have the animation on just the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jessica, I created a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/jackmoody/pen/gGQWWX) that should solve your problem. It looks like your rotation of your image is just too drastic for your liking. I edited it to a 0.2 degree rotation. Try the following CSS:

```
.blueBox {
    background-color: #1d88eb;
    width: 875px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 125px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.catapillarBox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
   -webkit-animation: tinywalk 500ms linear alternate infinite;
    animation: tinywalk 500ms linear alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes tinywalk {
  0%{ transform: rotate(0);}
  25%{ transform: rotate(-0.2deg);}
  50%{ transform: rotate(0.2deg);}
  75%{ transform: rotate(-0.2deg);}
  100%{ transform: rotate(0);}
}
img.caterpillar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    left:0;
    -webkit-animation: walk 20s forwards infinite linear;
    animation: walk 20s forwards infinite linear;
    z-index: 3;
}
@keyframes walk{
   0% { left: 0; transform: rotateY(0deg);}
  49% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
  50% {left: 700px; transform: rotateY(180deg);}
  99% {transform: rotateY(180deg);}
  100% {left: 0; transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, while this looks better I still see a little difference in the tinywalk animation at the end, is there a way to run both walk and tinywalk on the image?

Comment: Let me look into it

Comment: Jessica, to keep the same solution (using rotate), just make the rotations get progressively smaller as you move farther into your walk animation. Check my codepen again. I have updated it [here](https://codepen.io/jackmoody/pen/gGQWWX). You can change the degree rotations to your liking, but just make rotations smaller as you get farther into your walk (going to 50%) and then make the rotations larger as you go from 50% - 100%.

Comment: To get a really smooth animation, you need to add more keyframes. I will leave this up to you.